# Only the last subplot has minor gridlines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, subplot

I would like to plot a subplot with the dataframe columns so I perform the following code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,10), tight_layout=True)

plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(which='minor', linestyle='-', alpha=0.5)

ori_df.plot(x='Predicted', y='Actual', kind='scatter', ax=axes[0])
ori_df.plot(x='Predicted', y='# Difference', kind='scatter', ax=axes[1])

plt.show()
```

However, why does only the last plot have minor gridlines?
[image: subplots]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify each axis:

```
axes[0].grid(which='minor', linestyle='-', alpha=0.5)
axes[1].grid(which='minor', linestyle='-', alpha=0.5)
```

or:

```
for axis in axes:
    axis.grid(which='minor', linestyle='-', alpha=0.5)
```

Same for `minorticks_on()`